# Converting from ChatColor to Color Codes

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to make a minecraft plugin with the Spigot/Bukkit API. The plugin I'm trying to make is a bigger enderchest.

I'm currently working on a save method and I'm stuck on getting it to save the names of items. I can't get the color codes to work correctly. What I'm asking, is how you can translate from a ChatColor to a color code.

For example, from `ChatColor.GREEN + ChatColor.BOLD.toString() + "foo"` to `&a&lfoo`.

I have it so when the player opens their enderchest, it translates the saved name from `&a&lfoo` to `foo` that is green and bold. It uses #translateAlternateColorCodes. I have tried using #lastColors but that didn't seem to work.

Does anyone know a method to translate from colors to minecraft's '&' format. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: From the documentation [here](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Formatting_codes#Color_codes), it looks like the symbol to be used is `§`, not `&`.

Comment: @hnefatl that isn't used in game. You shouldn't use that symbol in java either. The only time that symbol is used is in the config. Even then, you should just use #translateAlternateColorCodes. The symbol isn't recognized when I try to save it as that either. It comes out as a ? in the text save file. It is hardly recognized by java. You can only use it in certain situations. The § shouldn't be used. Minecraft uses the & symbol for those reasons.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "It is hardly recognised by java" - java has support for unicode encoding, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/kcXbDD). Also look over the first point [here](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Talk:Formatting_codes#Ampersand_.28.26.29_vs._section_mark_.28.C2.A7.29), it looks like it's worth a try. Are you saving this "text save file" with unicode encoding, or with ascii?

Comment: Regardless, it's not what I was asking. I want to know how to convert from chat color to the minecraft color codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you ever got the answer to your question, so let me give this a go.

Bukkit API's built in alternate color codes method offers easy conversion. Just add a method that looks something like this:

```
public static String format (String str) {
    return ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', str);
}
```

If this doesn't work for you, there's a couple other ways you could do this with String manipulation. Just tell me if you need those, but if this works, this is the much easier way around.